# How is the x86 JAE instruction related to the carry flag?

Tags: assembly, x86

I have some x86 code which looks like:

```
;  The carry flag is set to 1 here
jae    an_address  ; The jump instruction does not take place
```

Does this make sense?

I thought the jump should take place because 1 is greater than or equal to 0, the definition of `JAE`?

Comment: I thought the JAE is based on the value of the carry flag, not the previous instruction?

Comment: FWIW, JAE does not compare the value of the carry flag to something else, it simply jumps if the carry flag is 0, no matter why it is 0. If it is 1, as you say, the jump should not take place.

Comment: specifically the mnemonic refers to a previous comparison (or subtraction). If a `cmp` was performed and the first operand was greater than or equal to the other, the carry flag will not be set (will be 0). It is this condition which `jae` branches on.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`jae` (**j**ump if **a**bove or **e**qual) is the same as `jnb` (**j**ump if **n**ot **b**elow) and `jnc` (**j**ump if **n**ot **c**arry), i.e. jump if CF == 0. The choice between all 3 mnemonics is up to the programmer. The CF isn't set here by `mov` but by a previous instruction.

The mnemonics `jae` and its logical synonym `jnb` are recommended after a compare instruction (`cmp`) which does subtraction, as opposed to `jnc` for cases where the CF is affected by bit operations (shifts, single-bit manipulations like `btc`, etc.).  It's the same machine code, but a different way to think about the meaning for human readers, in terms of a comparison result vs. in terms of the actual flag value itself.

You can get more details in Intel or AMD software developer manuals, or an HTML extract of just [Intel's vol.2 entry for `jcc`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jcc)

Answer (score 7):

`jae` means Jump if above or equal.  It will jump if the carry flag is equal to 0.

You're looking for `jnae` or `jb`

Comment: I'm not looking for anything :) I am looking at code which contains jae, CF is zero and the jump is not being taken?

Comment: You must be looking at something wrong, becasue that's not how jae behaves

Comment: Im debugging in Visual Studio, I can see the value of the carry flag and when I step-in, the debugger doesn't jump to the address of the branch, just continues right over it.

Comment: in your question you say the carry flag is 1, is this not the case?

Comment: Sorry- I meant carry is initially zero, then it is set to 1, then the JAE occurs and there's no branch.

Comment: Because JAE jumps when the carry flag is 0, so **if it is not 0**, the jump should **not** take place, as you observe.